# ARC App Crashes when accessing @property form ARC static lib

Tags: iphone, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, static-libraries, ios6

I have a ARC ([automatic-reference-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-reference-counting)) app that builds a static library (also ARC). The app will launch fine but when the an action is performed that reads or writes to a @property in the static library the app will crash with this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/0E7ADBB4-FFE5-4CEB-B418-8A35A92E99D4/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/0E7ADBB4-FFE5-4CEB-B418-8A35A92E99D4/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

All the advice has been about linking non-ARC libraries to ARC Apps (or vice-versa). But these are both ARC.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The app's `Base SDK` was set to iOS 6 and `iOS Deployment Target` was set to iOS 5.0 however for the static library both the `Base SDK` & `iOS Deployment Target` were set to iOS 6.

Making sure the  `Base SDK` & `iOS Deployment Target` matched in the app and library solved this problem.

Comment: Good point about making all parts match. Unless you plan to support iOS 6 features when available (and take on the large testing headaches, and extra feature-detection code required), I also recommend setting Base SDK and iOS Deployment Target to the same thing (iOS 5 in this case). Despite Apple's official statement that you should always link against the latest SDK, the Xcode team at WWDC agreed that that approach is very fragile because the compiler gives you no warnings when you use unsupported features incorrectly.

Comment: super - one of my many static libs had this issue - fixed it now - thank you.

Comment: How do you change the `Base SDK` and `iOS Deployment Target` for the static library?

Comment: @TomMedley This only applies if your library is a separate project and build at the same time as your app.

Comment: @rjstelling Yeah, I'm pretty sure I've encountered an [OpenCV bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2507).

Comment: @TomMedley Looks like OpenCV might need to recompile their framework, are you using Xcode 4.6? Updating to it might help.

Comment: @rjstelling I am. Compilation of the Framework is done locally.