# Crash with Google's Objective-c SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api, gdata-api, google-api-objc-client

I've been stuck with this problem for many days now.

I'm using google's objective-C SDK for getting user's name and email to login into my app.
I added the project and the classes to my project (because it didn't compile) and when testing everything goes right.

The problem is, when I compile for release and download the app directly into my iPad (iOS 5.1, it's working ok on ipads with iOS 6.0.1), the app is crashing when create google's login view controller.

the log sais:

> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic_copy 
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/58E1CEC8-FDAD-46B7-8684-92F919BA03A7/Nearpod.app/Nearpod
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib   Dyld Version: 199.6

I've been looking for this error and everything I found are things like these questions: [ARC App Crashes when accessing @property form ARC static lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641190/arc-app-crashes-when-accessing-property-form-arc-static-lib) and [Xcode 4.5 error on IOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404495/xcode-4-5-error-on-ios-5).

I've already checked that the Base SDK and IOS Development Target of both projects matches (Actually, this was what make the app work fine on Debug mode at first)

I have iOS Develpoment Target sett on 5.0 and Base SDK on Latest IOS (iOS 6.1)

I'd checked the differences between Debug and Release configs on both Projects and Target's and didn't found anything suspicious...

I've also added the -fobjc-arc flag to all gtl classes, and both projects.

can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you need to set the -all_load flag?

Comment: the flag was set on my project, I added it to the GTL project and target, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days on this and making major changes to my code, I discovered that the solution is unbelievably simple: Just make sure that the deployment version of the GTL project (or GData project) is the same as deployment target of your main [image: project].